# Console2 how to repeat last command?

Tags: windows, console2

Is there any way how to repeat last executed command (like up arrow does is cmd.exe) in [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/)?

Comment: The manual does say: Windows (CR+LF) - If selected the copy operation will convert the carriage return using the Windows convention. 
I don't know what that actually means but may be it will help

Comment: Um... I use Console2, and the up arrow works...

Comment: Yeah, I tried walkthough in this article: http://www.instructables.com/id/%22Drop-Down%22%2c-Quake-style-command-prompt-for-Window/?ALLSTEPS and it sort of stopped working (probably).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[I stand corrected, as per comments, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> works]**

<strike>From the developers themselves (at least, their source code):</strike>

> **NOTE:** Console is **NOT** a shell. Therefore, it does not implement shell features like...***command history***

Source: http://console.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=console/console;a=blob;f=help/html/introduction.html;h=3b7e5dcc8948366941e371dfe4946e2431d4e434;hb=041d573f735c50926185657558fb5491f0871dfd

Comment: Ha! Nevermind, i figured it out. All you have to do is press **Ctrl+Up**. Weird that the developers say the application does not support this function though.

Comment: Haha, well, to be fair the help file is usually the last thing I remember to update too.

Comment: You *make* a help file?! I just assume everyone will know by magic :)

Comment: I make a help file because **I** forget the s**t I code sometimes.

Comment: I just discovered that **Shift + ↑** works as well.

Comment: Shift+up did not work for me. @bitmind had the solution for me...

Answer (score 25):

You have to go to **Settings** -> **Hotkeys** and disable *Use scroll lock for scrolling*. This worked fine for me!

Comment: thx, save my time

Comment: This fixed the case where arrow keys (both up/down and left/right) cause scrolling instead of keypresses being passed on to the actual interpreter. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

If it was working previously, and suddenly stopped, you may have [hit the scroll lock key](http://www.lustforge.com/2011/04/02/console2-arrow-key-error/).

Comment: I have had this issue a couple of times now and I would have never figured out. Is the first time that I find a usage for the scroll lock key, even if it is annoying.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and none of the instructions above worked for me.

In my case noticed that in Settings -> Hotkeys UP and DOWN were assigned to "Scroll Buffer row up" and "Scroll Buffer row down", so I assigned something else to these Commands (ie: Crtl + UP, Crtl + DOWN) and the UP and DOWN keys started working again to navigate the  history.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, in the Settings - Behavior screen under Copy and Paste you can select Copy on Select. I know not ideal but may be the closest you can get.